# extract text from fixed width string

Tags: awk

How do I extract text from fixed width string?

For e.g. here is the output of docker history command...

```
# docker history mysql
IMAGE               CREATED             CREATED BY                                      SIZE                COMMENT
f008d8ff927d        3 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop)  CMD ["mysqld"]               0B
<missing>           3 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop)  EXPOSE 3306/tcp              0B
<missing>           3 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENTRYPOINT ["docker-ent...   0B
<missing>           3 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c ln -s usr/local/bin/docker-entr...   34B
<missing>           3 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop) COPY file:52f06a5715711e...   6.04kB
<missing>           3 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop)  VOLUME [/var/lib/mysql]      0B
<missing>           3 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c {   echo mysql-community-server...   242MB
<missing>           3 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c echo "deb http://repo.mysql.com...   55B
<missing>           3 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV MYSQL_VERSION=5.7.2...   0B
<missing>           2 months ago        /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV MYSQL_MAJOR=5.7          0B
<missing>           2 months ago        /bin/sh -c set -ex;  key='A4A9406876FCBD3C...   21.8kB
<missing>           2 months ago        /bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get insta...   38.6MB
<missing>           2 months ago        /bin/sh -c mkdir /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d    0B
<missing>           2 months ago        /bin/sh -c set -x  && apt-get update && ap...   4.52MB
<missing>           2 months ago        /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV GOSU_VERSION=1.7         0B
<missing>           2 months ago        /bin/sh -c groupadd -r mysql && useradd -r...   330kB
<missing>           2 months ago        /bin/sh -c #(nop)  CMD ["bash"]                 0B
<missing>           2 months ago        /bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD file:1dd78a123212328...   123MB
```

I need to select only third column "created by". This is what I have tried...

```
# docker history mysql | awk '{printf "%-20s  %-20s %-48s %-2s \n", $1,$2,$3,$4}'
IMAGE                 CREATED              CREATED                                          BY
f008d8ff927d          3                    weeks                                            ago
<missing>             3                    weeks                                            ago
<missing>             3                    weeks                                            ago
<missing>             3                    weeks                                            ago
<missing>             3                    weeks                                            ago
<missing>             3                    weeks                                            ago
<missing>             3                    weeks                                            ago
<missing>             3                    weeks                                            ago
<missing>             3                    weeks                                            ago
<missing>             2                    months                                           ago
<missing>             2                    months                                           ago
<missing>             2                    months                                           ago
<missing>             2                    months                                           ago
<missing>             2                    months                                           ago
<missing>             2                    months                                           ago
<missing>             2                    months                                           ago
<missing>             2                    months                                           ago
<missing>             2                    months                                           ago
```

I guess space is not field separator here. I need characters from 40th till 88th position.

Comment: with `awk` you could simply use `substr` function of it, added as Solution 2nd in my post too. But it is considering that your output is of fixed length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## print char 40 to char 88

```
   sed "s:^.\{40\}\(.\{48\}\).*:\1:" file
```

`1)` `^.\{40\}` - 40 chars from the beginning of the string (`.`-char, `{number of repeats}`)

`2)` `\(.\{48\}\)` - 48 additional chars (from 40 to 88 chars) .

`3)` `.*` - rest of the string

`4)` `\(\)`, `\1` - replacing the string with the 48 chars (from 40 to 88)

Answer (score 1):

If your history will be always same pattern then following may help you on same:

***Solution 1st:*** As OP mentioned width of output is fixed so using that tactic too here:

```
awk 'substr($0,41,48){print substr($0,41,48)}'  Input_file
```

***Solution 2nd:*** BY using `match` utility of `awk` here:

```
Your_command | awk '{match($0,/\/bin[^[:alnum:]].*/);num=split(substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH),array," ");for(i=1;i<=(num-1);i++){printf("%s%s",array[i],i==(num-1)?ORS:OFS)}}'
```

Adding a non-one liner form of solution too now:

```
your_command | awk '
{
  match($0,/\/bin[^[:alnum:]].*/);
  num=split(substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH),array," ");
  for(i=1;i<=(num-1);i++){
    printf("%s%s",array[i],i==(num-1)?ORS:OFS)}
}
'   Input_file
```

Output will be as follows:

```
/bin/sh -c #(nop) CMD ["mysqld"]
/bin/sh -c #(nop) EXPOSE 3306/tcp
/bin/sh -c #(nop) ENTRYPOINT ["docker-ent...
/bin/sh -c ln -s usr/local/bin/docker-entr...
/bin/sh -c #(nop) COPY file:52f06a5715711e...
/bin/sh -c #(nop) VOLUME [/var/lib/mysql]
/bin/sh -c { echo mysql-community-server...
/bin/sh -c echo "deb http://repo.mysql.com...
/bin/sh -c #(nop) ENV MYSQL_VERSION=5.7.2...
/bin/sh -c #(nop) ENV MYSQL_MAJOR=5.7
/bin/sh -c set -ex; key='A4A9406876FCBD3C...
/bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get insta...
/bin/sh -c mkdir /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
/bin/sh -c set -x && apt-get update && ap...
/bin/sh -c #(nop) ENV GOSU_VERSION=1.7
/bin/sh -c groupadd -r mysql && useradd -r...
/bin/sh -c #(nop) CMD ["bash"]
/bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD file:1dd78a123212328...
```